# mongodb таймауты: описание таймаутов и вопросы

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

В [монге](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) есть несколько видов таймаутов и мне интересно знать, как они работают. С некоторыми я разобрался, другие не даются мне. Сейчас я говорю про pyMongo, но думаю, что это распространяется и на саму БД.

**maxIdleTimeMS (optional)**: *The maximum number of milliseconds that a connection can remain idle in the pool before being removed and replaced. Defaults to None (no limit).*

Данный таймаут я не знаю, как объяснить. Если Вы сможете рассказать о нём детально, я буду Вам признателен.

**socketTimeoutMS**: *(integer or None) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait for a response after sending an ordinary (non-monitoring) database operation before concluding that a network error has occurred. Defaults to None (no timeout).*

Здесь всё очень просто. Если запрос длится более чем socketTimeoutMS, то следует считать, что произошла ошибка и следует оборвать соединение.

**connectTimeoutMS**: *(integer or None) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait during server monitoring when connecting a new socket to a server before concluding the server is unavailable. Defaults to 20000 (20 seconds).*

Данный таймаут вызывает ряд вопросов. По логике, он выставляет ограничение на установление connection. Иными словами, если соединение устанавливается более чем connectTimeoutMS, то следует считать, что произошла ошибка. Но, к сожалению, простой эксперимент, опровергает описание этого таймаута. Запустим скрипт:

```
driver = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_host, connectTimeoutMS=CONNECT_TIMEOUT)

print(driver.find())
```

В таком случае, окажется, что запрос будет ожидаться дефолтные 20 секунд (20000 миллисекунд). При этом, замечу, что я не mongodb_host образается на несуществующий endpoint. Назначение этого таймаута неясно.

**serverSelectionTimeoutMS**: *(integer) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait to find an available, appropriate server to carry out a database operation; while it is waiting, multiple server monitoring operations may be carried out, each controlled by connectTimeoutMS. Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds).*

Кажется, что данный таймаут нацелен на то, чтобы ограничивать время на поиск подходящего сервера. Т.е. если у вас запущено несколько экземпляров сервера, то время на выбор экземпляра (реплики) ограничено serverSelectionTimeoutMS. Но после экспериментов, я выяснил, что сначала отрабатывает serverSelectionTimeoutMS, а затем, если конкретная реплика была выбрана, то будет отрабатывать connectTimeoutMS. Иными словами, пока не будет выбран конкретный сервер, соединение будет отваливаться по serverSelectionTimeoutMS. Как только сервер выбран, запускается ограничение по таймауту connectTimeoutMS.

При этом, в доке указано, что на мониторинг тратится connectTimeoutMS. Означает ли это, что попытка установить соединение с каждой репликой будет равняться connectTimeoutMS? Или же под мониторингом имеется ввиду что-то ещё?

**waitQueueTimeoutMS**: *(integer or None) How long (in milliseconds) a thread will wait for a socket from the pool if the pool has no free sockets. Defaults to None (no timeout).*

Время ожидания свободного потока из пула доступных потоков.

**Таким образом, у меня появилось несколько вопросов**:

- Означает ли, что попытка установить соединение с каждой репликой будет равняться connectTimeoutMS? Или же под мониторингом имеется ввиду что-то ещё?
- Как работает maxIdleTimeMS?
- Правильно ли я понял схему работы с connectTimeoutMS и serverSelectionTimeoutMS?